# host MVC app inside a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website (not a web application- in visual studio you get two options-create a website/project) running on IIS 6.0. Now I want to develop few features in MVC architecture.
So I created one MVC application in visual studio and everything is working fine on localhost as a separate application. Now I want to host this MVC app also inside the website I have already deployed.

I created a virtual directory(MVCDir) inside the default website in IIS 6.0. The global.asax file which was in root folder I added the routing function-

```
Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}")



    routes.MapPageRoute("Default4", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", "~/MVCDir", False, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = Mvc.UrlParameter.Optional}))

End Sub
```

*** NOTE- If I write routes.ignoreRoute instead of routes,ignore it says- IgnoreRoute is not a member of System.Web.RoutingCollection*

I called this routing function inside application_start function
now when I run domain.com/home/index

How to solve this problem?
 it says resource not found

Comment: Oops, sorry, misunderstood - you're asking about forwarding requests from one IIS application into another one? However my point about the wildcard request handler stands: make sure you've registered a wildcard request handler for the root application and 'check file exists' is off.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a problem with you child application inheriting configuration from parent. I had a similar problem when trying to put an app under a website.

You'll need to wrap `<system.web>` in `<location>` tag with `inheritInChildApplications="false"`

Example:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>
</location>
```

[Here](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/04/solved-breaking-parent-webconfig.html) you have more detailed explanation.